# using EPiImageResizer in a Repeater

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

I'm not getting EPiImage to show me the image when I use it in a Repeater.

If I move the resizer outside of the Repeater it works like a charm..

Is there anything special I need to think about?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PageMenu" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <nav id="InlineSubNav">
            <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <EPiImage:EPiImageResizer PropertyName="Image" Width="150" Height="150" Transformation="ScaleToFill" runat="server" />
        <EPiServer:Property PropertyName="MainIntro" runat="server" />
        <EPiServer:Property PropertyName="PageLink" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code for EPIImageResizer, the Render method will pick the property from another page, providing that the PageLink is set:

```
    //If PageLink is set use that page instead of the current page
    if (PageLink != PageReference.EmptyReference)
      PageDataToUse = DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(PageLink);

    if (PageDataToUse[PropertyName] != null)
    {
      ImageUrl = PageDataToUse[PropertyName].ToString();
```

So providing you are setting the PageLink property correctly, then there shouldn't be a problem.

Try using the binding syntax to populate the PageLink property within the ItemTemplate on the repeater, using something like this:

```
    PageLink="<%# ((PageData)Container.DataItem).PageLink %>"
```

Alternatively set the value in the code behind by subscribing to the repeater's ItemDataBound event, retrieve the EPiImageResizer control using the e.Item.FindControl method and setting the PageLink using the value obtained from e.Item.DataItem.PageLink

Comment: This was fixed in epiimage 2.5

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see from the source code of EPiImage, it will not work/it's not supported.
You could try setting the PageLink property for each item.

Comment: I agree, is EPiImageResizer aware of the databinding context? If not, you will need to bind it's PageLink.

Comment: I tried adding the PageLink but then I get Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 1):

In EPiImage 2.5 the issue with databinding was fixed.

by specifying the both PropertyName and PageLink attribute it now works

```
<EPiImage:EPiImageResizer PropertyName="Image" PageLink="<%# Container.CurrentPage.PageLink %>" Width="150" Height="150" Transformation="ScaleToFill" runat="server" />
```